# Como usar URL amigável?

Tags: php, mysql, htaccess, url-amigável

Estou fazendo meu TCC e o tema é SEO, para completar preciso colocar URL amigável já que o link atual se encontra assim:

> postagem.php?id=79

Bom, já procurei sobre o .htaccess e consegui deixar as páginas principais (blog.php, contato.php, index.php e sobremim.php) amigáveis mas essas que são as postagens e são recuperadas do banco eu não consigo, gostaria de ajuda.

Código do .htaccess:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule ^contato/?$ contato.php [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^blog/?$ blog.php [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^sobremim/?$ sobremim.php [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^inicio/?$ index.php [NC,L]


</IfModule>
```

Programação que busca no banco:

```
<?php 
$mysql = new BancodeDados();
$mysql->conecta();

$ident = $_GET['id'];

//$query = mysqli_query($mysql->con,"select * from postagens where id = $ident");

$query = "SELECT * from postagens where id = $ident";

// executa a query e 'grava' o resultado em $res
$res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

// busca os campos da query
$campo = mysql_fetch_array($res);
// armazena cada campo do banco em uma variável
$tit = $campo["titulo"];
$subt = $campo["subtitulo"];
$textinho = $campo["conteudo"];
$imge = $campo["foto"];

$categ = $campo["categoria"];   

?>

<img class="card-img-top" src="admin/img/<?php echo $imge;?>">
   <div class="card-body">
   <h1><?php echo $tit ;?></h1>
   <h2><?php echo $subt ;?></h2>
   <p class="card-text"><?php echo $textinho ;?></p>
   </div>
   <br><br>
   <hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Julia! Seja bem-vinda! Eu costumo usar um gerador de URL amigável.
https://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

URL original:

`http://www.qualquercoisa.com/postagem.php?id=79`

URL amigável:

`http://www.qualquercoisa.com/id/79/`

Regra .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^id/([^/]*)/$ /postagem.php?id=$1 [L]
```